Is there a better way to load and unload data to and from an aligned memory location in C?
Here's the code for a working simple program that multiplies two (although here same) 16-byte float vectors through SSE and storing the output into s in C.
#include <xmmintrin.h>

float *data;

void sse_multiply() {
  __m128 s = _mm_mul_ps(_mm_load_ps(data), _mm_load_ps(data));
  // unload s in another float *result or even float *data...to get answer
}

int main() {
    data = aligned_alloc(16, 4 * sizeof(float));
    data[0] = 1.0f;
    data[1] = 2.0f;
    data[2] = 3.0f;
    data[3] = 4.0f;
    sse_multiply();
    return 0;
}

In godbolt.org, The above program generates the following assembly code when compiled with x86-64_GCC compiler:
data:
        .zero   8
sse_multiply:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR data[rip]
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-64], rax
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-64]
        movaps  xmm0, XMMWORD PTR [rax]
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR data[rip]
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-56], rax
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-56]
        movaps  xmm1, XMMWORD PTR [rax]
        movaps  XMMWORD PTR [rbp-32], xmm1
        movaps  XMMWORD PTR [rbp-48], xmm0
        movaps  xmm0, XMMWORD PTR [rbp-32]
        mulps   xmm0, XMMWORD PTR [rbp-48]
        movaps  XMMWORD PTR [rbp-16], xmm0
        nop
        pop     rbp
        ret
main:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     esi, 16
        mov     edi, 16
        call    aligned_alloc
        mov     QWORD PTR data[rip], rax
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR data[rip]
        movss   xmm0, DWORD PTR .LC0[rip]
        movss   DWORD PTR [rax], xmm0
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR data[rip]
        add     rax, 4
        movss   xmm0, DWORD PTR .LC1[rip]
        movss   DWORD PTR [rax], xmm0
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR data[rip]
        add     rax, 8
        movss   xmm0, DWORD PTR .LC2[rip]
        movss   DWORD PTR [rax], xmm0
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR data[rip]
        add     rax, 12
        movss   xmm0, DWORD PTR .LC3[rip]
        movss   DWORD PTR [rax], xmm0
        mov     eax, 0
        call    sse_multiply
        mov     eax, 0
        pop     rbp
        ret
.LC0:
        .long   1065353216
.LC1:
        .long   1073741824
.LC2:
        .long   1077936128
.LC3:
        .long   1082130432

You can see in main(), it's using the movss SSE instruction (move a single scaler float) into the index via every line of data[<index>] = <value>;. I know GCC puts the movss instruction when loading floats but movess is very slow. Also, Just to load 4 floats into float *data; we outputted 14 lines of assembly code which isn't good (below).
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR data[rip]
        movss   xmm0, DWORD PTR .LC0[rip]
        movss   DWORD PTR [rax], xmm0
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR data[rip]
        add     rax, 4
        movss   xmm0, DWORD PTR .LC1[rip]
        movss   DWORD PTR [rax], xmm0
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR data[rip]
        add     rax, 8
        movss   xmm0, DWORD PTR .LC2[rip]
        movss   DWORD PTR [rax], xmm0
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR data[rip]
        add     rax, 12
        movss   xmm0, DWORD PTR .LC3[rip]
        movss   DWORD PTR [rax], xmm0

My question is: Is there a better way to load & unload data to & from aligned memory locations in C, especially when working with SSE?

You compiled without optimizations.

we outputted 14 lines of assembly code which isn't good  "Lines of assembly code" is not a useful metric - it tells you almost nothing about performance.


we outputted 14 lines of assembly code which isn't good "Lines of assembly code" is not a useful metric - it tells you almost nothing about performance
Oh! Is there a better way to do a scaler operation and sse operation performance comparison @AndrewHenle?



You compiled without optimizations.
If I add -O3 flag, the code reduces down heavily. I'm measuring this operation (not in the dummy code above) via __rdtsc() (from x86instrin.h) cycle counter and I can't measure anything (output is 0). I expect this since the code is static (float values are constant) and thus optimized by GCC so no operations happen @interjay.


@Ayush Actually benchmark performance and profile your code.  Because that is what matters.

https://godbolt.org/z/hG4GxYzhf

@0___________ -Ofast seems to produce slightly different results.  Offhand, I don't think relaxing C standard compliance that -Ofast results in matters here.

Near duplicate of Why does clang produce inefficient asm with -O0 (for this simple floating point sum)? .  Also, avoid global variables, that makes it harder for the compiler to avoid actually storing the pointer to memory and reloading it.

Re: creating a microbenchmark, see Idiomatic way of performance evaluation? and How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output? re: writing small functions that compile to asm that's useful to look at.

I don't know what you call 'better', but you can make an array of __m128 vectors and use _mm_set_ps (or _mm_set1_ps) to fill in the values. Then you can just do the multiplication on the array elements.

Ayush, A better way to determine the allocation size: data = aligned_alloc(16, 4 * sizeof(data[0]));.  Easier to code right, review and maintain than data = aligned_alloc(16, 4 * sizeof(float));


Re: creating a microbenchmark, see Idiomatic way of performance evaluation? and How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output? @PeterCordes,  I read through it & I've slightly updated the code (https://godbolt.org/z/KW8WajnMT).  I'm still using __rdtsc() from x86intrin.h to measure the frequency cycles & thus estimate operation performance. If I enable optimization flags (-O3, -Os, -Ofast etc.), the benchmark get's optimised away and rdtsc is 0. I know of  volatile & __cpuid but I'm not sure how to use them effectively here.


__rdtsc() counts at a fixed frequency, not the CPU core clock frequency.  And as I wrote in my answer there, you need to use things like Benchmark::DoNotOptimize() in ways that stop the work you want to measure from being optimized away.  One mulps is too fast to usefully measure with rdtsc anyway, though.  It has 1/clock throughput and 4 cycle latency on most CPUs, both of which are much smaller than rdtsc's overhead of about 21 cycles.  (https://uops.info/).  So preferably put your code under test in a repeat loop to measure either its throughput or latency.

Oh, the code you linked on Godbolt does use a loop, but it has allocation and free inside the loop!  So you'd basically be measuring aligned_alloc performance.  (Except GCC optimizes away the alloc and free since it knows about those functions and doesn't consider alloc+free a visible side-effect).  Also, integer divide by ITERATION_COUNT truncates towards zero, so that's why you're printing exactly zero, instead of a small floating-point number like you'd normally want to calculate.

Thank you @PeterCordes! That makes so much sense. I now see why the code results in  this way. I fixed it by replacing __rdtsc() with clock_gettime() and by using CLOCK_MONOTONIC instead to measure the time taken by the operation. The SSE time stays consistent although scaler ops's time fluctuate but I can see a 1.2x-2x performance improvement from Scaler to SSE which is reasonable.
